# To drag and drop, parent and child elements separately

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

For an example, i have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncvwnxch/) where i can drag the parent and child elements.

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
   <ul>
      parent1
      <li>child1</li>
      <li>child2</li>
      <li>child3</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      parent2
      <li>child1</li>
      <li>child2</li>
      <li>child3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#container ul,li").draggable();
```

Here, when i drag, the parent element, the child elements are also drag along with it. What i really need is, drag them separately. When i drag the parent, the parent element alone should drag and when dragging the child, the child element should alone should drag. How is it possible?

Please suggest a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a parent without it's children doesn't make sense in most situations, so you probably won't find an out-of-the-box solution.

If it's possible to alter the HTML, something like this might work for you.

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
    <ul>
        <li>parent1</li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <ul>
                <li>child1</li>
                <li>child2</li>
                <li>child3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that `<li>` is the only valid child of `<ul>`, but `<ul>` is a valid child of `<li>`.

**jQuery**

```
$("#container ul li:first, #container ul li ul li").draggable();
```

Here's the result on **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u8g1mpbj/1/)**.

Comment: @Magnus Engdal, But if the list is too long with many number of ul and li how this is possible?